# clear cache from information_schema.tables in mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to clear the cache in information_schema.tables in mysql 5.6 running this query

```
 $this->db->query("SET information_schema_stats_expiry = 0");
```

but this is not working in 5.6. Is there any otherway to clear cache without upgrading  mysql version.

Comment: There is one way using `FLUSH TABLES`;
But next time you query, the performance might be slow as data will be reloaded from the disk; Are you fine with this ?

Comment: @Tushar i was trying to get autoincrement id , `$getMaxID = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '" . $this->user . "'");` but due to cache it is returning wrong auto increment id any other solution to fix this issue